# Video Album List using MediaStore

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

Is there an **efficient** way to group all **Video** items by their ALBUM field using MediaStore?

As far as I know, you can loop through all videos and save the Album in an Array or something, but I've not found a way to do this in a simple and efficient way, possibly in a single step.

I'm looking for something like a "group by" clause in the query of the ContentResolver.

Any advice will be appreciated.